# Can't Get CSS Drop-Down Menu to Work

Tags: html, css

I have tried several code examples, none of them work...I created a blank HTML and CSS document, just for testing. This is what I have now; it doesn't seem to be working:

HTML:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <head>
 <meta charset=utf-8 />
 <title>Test</title>
 </head>
 <body>
 <nav id="nav">
   <ul>
    <li>Home</li>
   <li>Menu1
    <ul>
     <li>Sub1</li>
     <li>Sub2</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>Menu2
   <ul>
    <li>Sub1</li>
    <li>Sub2</li>
  </ul>
 </li>
 </ul>
</nav>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
nav ul li {
   display:  block;
   float: left;
   width: relative;
}
nav ul ul {
   display: none;  
}
nav ul li:hover > ul {
   display: block;
   position: absolute;
   margin-left: -30px;}

nav ul ul li {
 display: block; 
   float: none;
}
```

Comment: This seems to work in Chrome.  Here's a JSFiddle for this: http://jsfiddle.net/f2xs7/

Comment: worked for me? http://jsfiddle.net/cbrickhouse/PX3mN/

Comment: I'm using Chrome, and when I open the browser page up (on local host) it doesn't work. Any reason why this would be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change `width` in your `nav ul li` rule to be `position`. See this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nVd9k/).

```
nav ul li {
   display:  block;
   float: left;
   position: relative;
}
```

Comment: That doesn't fix it; although I don't know why I had width: relative instead of position...Anyway. EDIT: Note, my mouse isn't even over any of the menu items.

This is what I get in Chrome:

http://imgur.com/Fxg7FBs

Comment: Then your css file might not even be include/loaded. Do you know what the `console` (or dev tools) is within a browser?

Comment: Durrr. That was it >_< Haha. I forgot to link my CSS file.

Comment: Cool!  I would love to get credit ****wink**** for helping you solve your issue! Haha